# Sorting Imported Records from JSON Document

Tags: javascript

I have an object which is imported from a JSON document, which is organized like so:

```
[{
  'Surname': 'Surname',
  'FirstName': 'FirstName'
}
(...)
]
```

I read the file, run JSON.Parse, and have an object which integrates well with other functions in my application.  My issue is sorting this list by names.

I try the following code, and my logger on the first line of the compare function is noting that both arguments are undefined.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const pList = dataService.getLocalSaveData();
pList.sort(sortingUtil.compareByName());
```

When I iterate through the object like this, all of the data is present and functional:

```
for (var x of pList) {
    innerList += generateItemFromPerson(x);
  }
```

Comment: you probably don't want the () after compareByName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pList.sort(sortingUtil.compareByName());
```

In this line, you are invoking the function rather than passing it as an argument. I believe what you are looking for is:

```
pList.sort(sortingUtil.compareByName);
```

Comment: Thanks - these details in my switch from C languages to JS are killing me,.